# Google Play Support Contact

Tags: android

My Android app was accepted by Google Play Console administrators.
But it has never showed in Google Play Store.
I've contacted (responded to the initial email sent stating that it was ready for open testing). They have never responded!!

I've confirmed that the app was marked as "open for testing".
I've put 2 other apps Google Play Store.

QUESTION: How can I contact them?

THANKS for your help!!

Contacted them, expecting a response.